# How to add the last two elements in a list and add the sum to existing list

Tags: python

I am learning Python and using it to work thru a challenge found in Project Euler. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to get around this problem.

The problem:

> Even Fibonacci numbers
>
> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the
> previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will
> be:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
>
> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not
> exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

I created a for loop that adds the second to last element and the last element from the list x:

```
x = [1,2]
    
for i in x:
    second_to_last = x[-2]
    running_sum = i + second_to_last
```

If you run the above, you get 3. I am looking to add this new element back to the original list, x, and repeat the process. However, each time I try to use the append() function, the program crashes and keeps on running without stopping. I tried to use a while loop to stop this, but that was a complete failure. Why am I not able to add or append() the new element (running_sum) back to the original list (x)?

UPDATE:

I did arrive at the solution (4613732), but I the work to getting there did not seem efficient. Here is my solution:

```
while len(x) in range(1,32):
    
    for i in x:
        second_to_last = x[-2]
        running_sum = i + second_to_last
            
    x.append(running_sum)
    
print(x)

new_x = []

for i in x:
    if i%2 == 0:
        new_x.append(i)
sum(new_x)
```

I did have to check the range to see visually whether I did not exceed 4 million. But as I said, the process I took was not efficient.

Comment: since you are adding to the list. The list will keep growing forever. You need to provide condition when to stop.

Comment: To BUILD the list, you just need `while x[-1] < 4000000:` / `x.append( x[-2] + x[-1] )`

Comment: Thank you! That is definitely what I should have used.

Comment: To solve the problem, you don't need to create a list to hold all numbers of the fibonacy sequence.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep adding elements to a list while iterating over that list, the iteration will never finish.

You will need some other criterion to abort the loop - for example, in this case

```
if running_sum > 4000000:
    break
```

would work.

(Note that you don't strictly speaking need a list at all here; I'd suggest experimenting a bit with it.)

Comment: Hi Christoph, 

Sorry, this is first time using Stackoverflow, and not sure whether I am responding back correctly. After experimenting more with it, I did stumble on the right solution (I think...):

while len(x) in range(1,10):
    
    for i in x:
        second_to_last = x[-2]
        running_sum = i + second_to_last
    x.append(running_sum)

This did seem to do the trick.

Comment: No, that doesn't do the trick.  Your answer out to 4,000,000 should be 4,613,732.  Is that what you get?

Comment: Hi Tim Roberts. Yes, after some additional more experimenting, I finally arrived at that value:

while len(x) in range(1,32):
    
    for i in x:
        second_to_last = x[-2]
        running_sum = i + second_to_last
            
    x.append(running_sum)
    
print(x)

new_x = []

for i in x:
    if i%2 == 0:
        new_x.append(i)
sum(new_x)

Answer (score 0):

Here are two different ways to solve this.  One of them builds the whole list, then sums the even elements.  The other one only keeps the last two elements, without making the whole list.

```
fib = [1,2]
while fib[-1] < 4000000:
    fib.append(fib[-2]+fib[-1])
# Get rid of the last one, since it was over the limit.
fib.pop(-1)
print( sum(i for i in fib if i % 2 == 0) )


fib = (1,2)
sumx = 2
while True:
    nxt = fib[0]+fib[1]
    if nxt >= 4000000:
        break
    if nxt % 2 == 0:
        sumx += nxt
    fib = (fib[1],nxt)
print(sumx)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't answer your question about list modification but the solution for your problem:

```py
def sum_even_number_fibonacci(limit):
    n0 = 0 # Since we don't care about index (n-th), we can use n0 = 0 or 1
    n1 = 1
    even_number_sum = 0
    while n1 <= limit:
        if n1 % 2 == 0:
            even_number_sum += n1
        n2 = n0 + n1
        # Only store the last two number of the Fibonacci sequence to calculate the next one
        n0 = n1
        n1 = n2
    return even_number_sum

sum_even_number_fibonacci(4_000_000)
```